# iBatis IsEqual compare multiple values in one tag

Tags: ibatis

I'm working on a project with **iBatis 2.3**. I was wondering if is possible having a multiple value comparison in the same tag.

example:

```
<isEqual property="test" compareValue="A OR B">
 ....mySQL...
</isEqual>

<isEqual property="test" compareValue="A AND B">
 ....mySQL...
</isEqual>
```

Currently i'm using a list of statements for `OR` conditions:

```
<isEqual property="test" compareValue="A">
     ....mySQL...
</isEqual>
<isEqual property="test" compareValue="B">
     ....mySQL...
</isEqual>
```

and nested  tags to obtain `AND` condition, 
but the readability is low and is not relly clear the bond between two tags witch are part of the same condition.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible if A and B are in a list, and I guess they aren't. So if you pass A and B as a list parameter you could do the next:

```
<iterate prepend=”AND” open=”(” close=”)” conjunction=”OR”>
    test=#[]#
</iterate>
```

If not, you need to use different tags, something like next:

```
 <dynamic prepend="where">
 < isEqual prepend="and" property="test" compareValue="A">
  ...
 </isEqual>
< isEqual prepend="and" property="test" compareValue="B">
 ...
 </isEqual>
 </select>
```

Comment: Unfortunately is not what i need. With <iterate> i can make SQL conditions. I'm trying to have conditions in a ibastis tag. Thanks for the answer eatherway

Comment: So is not possible what you want.